# How do I convert my codes to correct jsx format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am newbie in Reactjs. This is my code. I want the Link component to just wrap the Card component. 
but when my codes are like this, reactjs fails me. How can I write these codes correctly ??

```
const ImageFrame = ({ movieId, movieName, searchWord, image, personMovieId, clickable, clearFavouriteMovie }) => {

return (
        <div className = "col-sm-3 mt-5 animated fadeInLeftBig ">
            { clickable ? /* if clickable props is true --> go movie, else go movie again but with personal movie id ! */
                 <Link to={{ pathname:`/movie/${movieId}`, movieName: `${movieName}`, searchWord: `${searchWord}` }}>
                    <Card className = "card-box image-frame  ">
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} alt="movieImg" />
                    </Card>
                    </Link> **!!! I WANT Link component stays here !!!** 
                    { 
                        clearFavouriteMovie && <button
                            className = "mt-3 btn btn-warning"
                            onClick = { () => clearFavouriteMovie(movieId)}
                        > Bu Filmi Sil </button> 
                    }

                : 
                <Link to = {{pathname: `/movie/${personMovieId}`}}>  {/* Person Known For Movies*/}
                <Card className = "bg-dark text-light card-box  image-frame " style = {{maxHeight: "500px"}}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} alt="movieImg" />
                </Card>
                </Link>
            }            
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: What error codes are you getting, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks  for fast feedback.  I want the Link component this way because whenever I click on the delete Movies button, it redirects me to that link via Link.  My error is  :   Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ":"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if statement can only return one element, in this case you're trying to return two `<Link>` and `<button>` to make this in to one use a `<React.fragment>`

Example

```
const ImageFrame = ({ movieId, movieName, searchWord, image, personMovieId, clickable, clearFavouriteMovie }) => {

return (
        <div className = "col-sm-3 mt-5 animated fadeInLeftBig ">
            { clickable ? /* if clickable props is true --> go movie, else go movie again but with personal movie id ! */
                 <React.fragment>
                 <Link to={{ pathname:`/movie/${movieId}`, movieName: `${movieName}`, searchWord: `${searchWord}` }}>
                    <Card className = "card-box image-frame  ">
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} alt="movieImg" />
                    </Card>
                    </Link> **!!! I WANT Link component stays here !!!** 
                    { 
                        clearFavouriteMovie && <button
                            className = "mt-3 btn btn-warning"
                            onClick = { () => clearFavouriteMovie(movieId)}
                        > Bu Filmi Sil </button> 
                    }
                </React.fragment>
                : 
                <Link to = {{pathname: `/movie/${personMovieId}`}}>  {/* Person Known For Movies*/}
                <Card className = "bg-dark text-light card-box  image-frame " style = {{maxHeight: "500px"}}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} alt="movieImg" />
                </Card>
                </Link>
            }            
        </div>
    )
```